# how to use icon in MenuItem using React Fluent UI

Tags: reactjs, menu, fluent

I am trying to add icon in MenuButton menuItem fluentui icon is working in button but give me error in menuItem.

this is the error

`export 'FavoriteStarFill' (imported as 'FavoriteStarFill') was not found in '@fluentui/react-icons' (possible exports: AccessTime20Filled,`

`

```
  import {bundleIcon,CalendarMonthFilled,CalendarMonthRegular,FavoriteStarFill} from "@fluentui/react-icons";
  
  <Menu>
    <MenuTrigger disableButtonEnhancement>
      <MenuButton appearance="transparent" icon={<CalendarMonth />}>
        Transparent
      </MenuButton>
    </MenuTrigger>

    <MenuPopover>
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem appearance="transparent" icon={<FavoriteStarFill/>}>Item a</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Item b</MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
    </MenuPopover>
  </Menu>
```

`

Comment: [menubutton ](https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/components-button-menubutton--default)